# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

In my application I want to schedule mail using Spring Scheduler an below are my code.

application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cnerge.dashboard"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/resources/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
      <property name="order" value="1" />
      <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
           <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
           <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
           <entry key="rss" value="application/rss+xml" />
        </map>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    scope="singleton" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/LdapConfig.properties"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="scheduleMailCronTrigger"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduleMailCronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="mailDetails" ref="scheduleMailJob"/>
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduleMailJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="sendMailController" ref="sendMailController"/>
        <!-- <property name="mailScheduleAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry Key="sendMailController" value-ref="sendMailController"></entry>
            </map>
        </property> -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="sendMailController" class="com.cnerge.dashboard.controller.SendMailController">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="secure.emailsrvr.com" />
        <property name="port" value="465"/>
        <property name="username" value="${mail.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${mail.password}"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

SendMailController.java

```
package com.cnerge.dashboard.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.cnerge.dashboard.pojo.EmailUser;

@Controller
public class SendMailController {

    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/sendMail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public @ResponseBody void toSendMail(@RequestBody EmailUser emailUser){

        String recipient = emailUser.getRecipient();
        String cc = emailUser.getCc();
        String subject = emailUser.getSubject();

        System.out.println("To:" + recipient);
        System.out.println("cc:" + cc);
        System.out.println("subject" + subject);

        SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mail.setTo(recipient);
        mail.setCc(cc);
        mail.setSubject(subject);

        mailSender.send(mail);
    }
}
```

While starting tomcat server I am giving below error.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/impl/triggers/CronTriggerImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/impl/triggers/CronTriggerImpl
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:860)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 43 more
```

I am not configuring RequestMapping in bean then to I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your Quartz jar file into latest version quartz-2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `quartz.jar` in your classpath. Add it and the error should gone.

Comment: I have added quartz.jar file version 1.8.6 in pom file.